# I have populated all the 4 issues dropdowns but I am having trouble populating their corresponding Outcome dropdowns

Tags: angularjs

I am new to Angularjs. I have 8 dropdowns on my page and each outcome dropdown is dependent on its corresponding issue dropdown: e.g Outcome_1 is dependent on Issue_1, Outcome_2 is dependent on Issue_2 etc.
I have populated all the 4 issues dropdowns but I am having trouble populating their corresponding Outcome dropdowns.

If 1 select “OCF 18” option in the first dropdown then it should populate first outcome dropdown options which are ("Reasonable and Necessary", "Partially reasonable and necessary", "Not reasonable and necessary", "Not applicable", "Unable to determine"), if 1 select “Applicability of the MIG” option in the first dropdown then it should populate first outcome dropdown options which are ("Meets MIG Guidelines", "Does not meet MIG Guidelines", "Not applicable", "Unable to determine").

```
$scope.SelectedLine = [
    {
        "Event_ID": "13970897",
        "IssueOutcomes": {
            "List": [
                {
                    "Issue": {
                        "Name": "OCF 18",
                        "Outcomes": [
                            "Reasonable and Necessary",
                            "Partially reasonable and necessary",
                            "Not reasonable and necessary",
                            "Not applicable",
                            "Unable to determine"
                        ]
                    }
                },
                {
                    "Issue": {
                        "Name": "Applicability of the MIG",
                        "Outcomes": [
                            "Meets MIG Guidelines",
                            "Does not meet MIG Guidelines",
                            "Not applicable",
                            "Unable to determine"
                        ]
                    }
                }
            ]
        },
        "Issue_1": "Applicability of the MIG",
        "Outcome_1": "Meets MIG Guidelines",
        "Issue_2": "Applicability of the MIG",
        "Outcome_2": "Does not meet MIG Guidelines",
        "Issue_3": "Income Replacement",
        "Outcome_3": "Not applicable",
        "Issue_4": "Housekeeping and Home Maintenance",
        "Outcome_4": "Unable to determine"
    }

];
```

```html
<select ng-model="SelectedLine.Issue_1" class="form-control"> 
 <option ng-repeat="Temp in SelectedLine.IssueOutcomes.List" value="{{Temp.Issue.Name}}">{{Temp.Issue.Name}}</option>
</select>
<select ng-model="SelectedLine.Outcome_1" class="form-control"></select>


<select ng-model="SelectedLine.Issue_2" class="form-control"> 
 <option ng-repeat="Temp in SelectedLine.IssueOutcomes.List" value="{{Temp.Issue.Name}}">{{Temp.Issue.Name}}</option>
</select>
<select ng-model="SelectedLine.Outcome_2" class="form-control"></select>


<select ng-model="SelectedLine.Issue_3" class="form-control"> 
 <option ng-repeat="Temp in SelectedLine.IssueOutcomes.List" value="{{Temp.Issue.Name}}">{{Temp.Issue.Name}}</option>
</select>
<select ng-model="SelectedLine.Outcome_3" class="form-control"></select>


<select ng-model="SelectedLine.Issue_4" class="form-control"> 
 <option ng-repeat="Temp in SelectedLine.IssueOutcomes.List" value="{{Temp.Issue.Name}}">{{Temp.Issue.Name}}</option>
</select>
<select ng-model="SelectedLine.Outcome_4" class="form-control"></select>
```

Comment: Can you change the structure of `SelectedLine` or must you use its current structure?

Comment: I can change it. Please suggest.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Karim Ali,

Thanks for a fun question; that was a real brain workout for me. I would change the structure of `SelectedLine` (i call it `data` in my code below) to divide it into three parts: The `issues`, the `outcomes`, and the `selections`. Since you want one issue and one outcome dropdown for each issue that exists, the `selections` part of the data must have the same number of elements as `issues`.  This is my data model:

```
data = {
    "Issues":[
        {
            "name": "OCF 18",
            "issue_id":0
        },
        {
            "name": "Applicability of the MIG",
            "issue_id":1
        }

    ],
    "Outcomes": [
        {
            "name": "Reasonable and Necessary",
            "issue_id":0
        },
        {
            "name": "Partially reasonable and necessary",
            "issue_id":0
        },
        {
            "name": "Not reasonable and necessary",
            "issue_id":0
        },
        {
            "name": "Not applicable",
            "issue_id":0
        },
        {
            "name": "Meets MIG Guidelines",
            "issue_id":1
        },
        {
            "name":  "Does not meet MIG Guidelines",
            "issue_id":1
        },
        {
            "name": "Not applicable",
            "issue_id":1
        },
        {
            "name": "Unable to determine",
            "issue_id":1
        }
    ],
    "Selections": [
        {
            "issue_id":null,
            "outcome":null
        },
        {
            "issue_id":null,
            "outcome":null
        }           
    ]
}
```

Note that each outcome has the `issue_id` of the issue it belongs to.  In the `HTML`, the idea is to show all issues in the dropdowns, but only show the outcomes that belong to the selected issue by using the `filter` pipe (otherwise all outcomes from all issues would be shown).

```
<!--Cycle through all issues because we want as many dropdown groups 
as we have issues -->
<div ng-repeat="Issue in data.Issues">
    <!-- $index is the iteration count: 0 on first iteration
    , 1 on second iteration...  Link the selected issue to 
    the matching index in data.Selections. Store the issue_id, 
    not the name, as the value (we need it to filter for 
    the right outcomes -->
    <select ng-model="data.Selections[$index].issue_id" 
            class="form-control">
        <!-- show all the issues in every dropdown -->
        <option ng-repeat="Temp in data.Issues" 
                value="{{Temp.issue_id}}">
            {{Temp.name}}
        </option>
    </select>

    <!-- Link the selected outcome to the same data.Selections 
    element as above. This will mean that every
    Selections[i] will hold the issue_id selected and the
     outcome name selected from that issue -->
    <select ng-model="data.Selections[$index].outcome" 
            class="form-control">

    <!-- Since all outcomes for all issues are in data.Outcomes, 
    we have to apply a filter to show only those outcomes matching
      the selected issue. The filter below says to show only 
      those outcomes whose 'issue_id' property matches the issue_id
      of Selections[$index], the currently selected issue id -->
        <option ng-repeat="outcome in data.Outcomes 
        | filter: {issue_id: data.Selections[$index].issue_id}"                
                value="{{outcome.name}}">
            {{outcome.name}}
        </option>
    </select>
    <hr/>
</div>
```

When an issue is selected, its `issue_id` is stored in `Selections` (1st dropdown is tied to first item in `Selections`...).  As soon as the `issue_id` is stored, the `filter` pipe will update the outcomes shown to display only the outcomes matching that `issue_id`. Then when one of those outcomes is selected, its `name` is stored next to the `issue_id` in `Selections`

Hope that's helpful.

Comment: Thank you.You did a nice job but i was expecting only ""IssueOutcomes" section to be changed in SelectedLine. In your case the whole SelectedLine is changed which i can't accept due to lack of completion time. Is it possible to provide solution with my structure.

Comment: I made sure to ask you whether you could change the structure before I wrote the answer and you said you could change it. I'm sorry it wasn't more helpful.  PS: What do you mean by "can't accept due to lack of completion time"?

Comment: I know you asked me changing the structure before but I was expecting only ""IssueOutcomes" section to be changed in SelectedLine. I have tight deadlines. If I go with your structure, then I have to change so much in my page. Again no hard feelings. Just a confusion about the whole structure or part of the structure.

Comment: No hard feelings. It can be done without changing anything besides `IssueOutcomes` if you use a `change` handler in Javascript to update `outcomes` dropdown options when a corresponding `issues` dropdown selection changes.  You may also be able to do it all within the template as I do on this solution if you know that your number of issue-outcomes dropdown pairs is fixed. It wouldn't be an elegant solution and I haven't given it that much thought but I'm pretty sure it can be done. It's a good amount of work though, which may explain why everyone else passed on writing up a solution.

Comment: Hi Patrick, since you are the only one who helped me and your solutions works too though with a different structure, I am going to accept your answer.

Comment: Thanks Karim. I hope you were able to get your work done by the deadline.